# Issue with recursive click on same element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Recurivesly called onclick on same element only twice but click action doesn't follow default action,
Idea is that when user click on `<input />`
it should not popup the file explorer but at first do some async task and
then call click action without user gesture, which in turn open file explorer.

Sample problem

https://jsbin.com/zuzinen/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<body>
  <input id="inp" type="file" />
</body>


var clicked = false;

function takePermission(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      clicked = true;
      cb();
    }, 2000);
}

function handleClick(e) {
  console.log(clicked)
  if (!clicked) {
    e.preventDefault();
    takePermission(function() {
      document.getElementById('inp').click();
    });

  }
}

document.getElementById('inp').onclick = handleClick;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? An output every 2 seconds for ever and ever? What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: It seems very unclear what your asking for.

Comment: i want there should be only one .click function call should be there but it should be open file explorer modal popup that is not happening, which is actually the desired behaviour

Comment: @trincot please look into this i have edited the problem statement

Comment: You can only trigger the file dialog from within a user event handler. With setTimeout you are no longer in that condition.

Comment: but why this works

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('inp').click();
});`

Comment: @trincot put some light on it

Answer (score 0):

After the first click you assign clicked to true, this means that your if statement does not fire.

So there is no more calls to click() after the first one.

Comment: thanks Nando
this is i also want there should be only one .click function call should be there
but it should be open file explorer modal popup that is not happening, which is actually the desired behaviour